# window open does not work after form submit

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following function to commit the values to a mysql database. The php ajax call works fine. But after the insert function, it does not execute the code related to window.open where it should go to index.html page.

```
function sendval(){
var tosubmit = validateForm();
if(tosubmit){
    showprog();

    // now create the json string to insert in the database
   var myData = {};
   myData.EmpName=localStorage.getItem("username");
   myData.LeaveType = $( "#leavetype option:selected" ).text();
   myData.LeaveStart = $('#txtFromDate').val();
   myData.LeaveEnd = $('#txtToDate').val();
   myData.ContactNum = $('#contactnum').val();
   myData.Comments = $('#Comments').val();
   myData.UsrMail = localStorage.getItem("usermail");
   myData.SupMail = localStorage.getItem("supmail");
   myData.Status = 'Submit';

    var myjson = JSON.stringify(myData);
    $.ajaxSetup( { "async": false } );
    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "submitleave.php",
    data: {"points": myjson}
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        if(msg == 'Success') {
            alert("Submission successful");
        } else {
            alert("Could not sumbit - try again");
        }
        $.ajaxSetup( { "async": true } );   
        window.open("index.html","_self");
    }); 
  } else {
        alert("Please enter valid values before submitting the form");
  }

}
```

I tried a few iterations but do not seem to get the error.

Some of the other functions do not work as well.

```
<header>XXXXX<br>
<br><input type="button" value="Logoff" id="logoff">
</header>

$('#logoff').click(function(){
   localStorage.clear();
   window.open("index.html","_self");
});
```

Regards,

Comment: don't use `async:false`  it blocks the UI, which is a terrible practice, and is now being deprecated by the browser vendors